# Why is the vertical component of the hydrostatic force on curved surface equal to the weight of the imaginary volume of liquid enclosed?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics

Why is the vertical component of the hydrostatic force on curved surface equal to the weight of the imaginary volume of liquid enclosed?
I tried to understand it by concept of equilibrium but a bit of discussion would really help. Thank you
[image: Talking about this cylindrical gate. I read that the vertical force on it due to the liquid outside will be equal in magnitude to the weight of the water enclosed which is imaginary, though opposite direction that is upwards.]

Comment: What do you mean by "the imaginary volume of liquid enclosed"? How, exactly, is the volume enclosed, and why is it imaginary?

Comment: I added a diagram @Philip Wood

Comment: So you have a submerged object and you are asking about the force on it from the surrounding fluid? In that case you are asking about Archimedes' principle. Physics Stack Exchange has several answers dealing with the principle and how it arises.

Comment: Thank you.......

Comment: A simple derivation is to consider the fluid, A, that is displaced by the body, B. This fluid was in equilibrium, that is its weight is balanced by the resultant of the upward forces on it from the surrounding fluid. B must be acted by this same resultant hydrostatic force (since A and B are exactly the same shape). Therefore B experiences an upward force equal to the weight of fluid displaced! Other derivations are possible.

Comment: Yes got it. Thank you so much.